# Cinema UML Class Diagram feedback

Tags: class, uml, class-diagram

I wanted your feedback about this UML case diagram. It is made for a cinema management system.

Please tell me if I have any  mistakes or if there is anything to edit.

[image: class diagram]

Comment: Please come up with a specific question.

Comment: For example, Shopper can view many Movies but must write only one Review. It does not seem to be correct :-)

Comment: Sorry, I don't reaaly have a specific question. I was just asking if it makes sense or If you have any edits that I should make.

Comment: Thanks @zer0hedge , I edited it.

Comment: There are a couple of improvements possible. There is one error: the composition implies that the ticket exists before the booking, which seems not in line with the fact that customer makes/purchases the booking. In general remove the aggregation and the compositions unless you really mean to use them and preferably with a whole/part semantic.

Comment: @Christophe One error? There are lots. This is a database design. Not a class design.

Comment: @qwerty_so well, you may have a more trained eye ;-) I only mentioned the point where I saw objective evidence of a formal error without need for further clarification; and I advised to get rid of the aggregation to avoid a strange * multiplicity on the wrong side.  I'd of course  have of course some questions about the Admin class and its relation with the other, which seems not so clear  and possibly incorrect.  But since the question is closed, it makes no sense to investigate further.